# mirroring on sql server 2012 on different windows server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, mirroring, windows-server

I have 2 servers *.203 and  *.205

I have sql server 2012 on each of them

I tried to make mirroring between them 
every thing goes successfuly but
when I tried to start mirroring 
it gives me exception as image below

[image]

Comment: Error 1418 is wide on and can be caused due to numerous issues its difficult to predict what is actual problem. MS has documented this error and its resolution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa337361.aspx plus you can also refer to this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/grahamk/archive/2008/12/08/database-mirroring-error-1418-troubleshooter.aspx

Comment: @Shanky how can I make mirroring between 2 servers not located under the same domain in windows server 2012 and also I use SQL server 2012 , I already get sucked , I do all steps correcltly but I have the same error